# ETL using azure table storage

Tags: azure, etl, azure-table-storage

Is there a way i can transform per minute data logged in azure table storage  to hourly ,daily and monthly tables?

I have heard of stream analytics and data lake but don't get how this can be done through above two technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know we could do that with [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-introduction) easily on the azure portal . Please have a try to follow my detail steps.

1.Login the [Azure new Portal](http://portal.azure.com)

2.Add a Data Factory

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.Click [Copy data (preview)] to set properties, we can set  **Recurring pattern** as minute , hourly, daily …as we like

[image]

4.Choose the source data  store as we like, in the demo I choose azure blob  table.
[image]

5.Specify new Azure storage connection

[image]

6.Select tables from the azure storage which to copy data

[image]

7.Apply filter if we want to

[image]

8.Select destination data store

[image]

9.Table mapping

[image]

10.Select Parallel copy settings

[image]

11.Get the setting summary

[image]

12.We can check that copy action has been done from Data Factory

[image]

13.Check  from the Azure storage table

[image]