# Copy Azure Storage Tables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Thanks to [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy), it is quite easy to transfer data between different azure storage accounts in command line. But I failed to find an efficient way to copy Azure Table Storage in C#. I noticed that there is an [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) that claims to power the Azcopy, but seems there is no direct way to copy tables according to the [library reference](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-net-data-movement/html/d194ffb9-b4cc-cefa-5988-bc9eb195cefe.htm). Any suggestions to implement that efficiently?

P.S. I have millions of entities to transfer now and then, and I prefer to integrate it in a C# project without using `cmd.exe` or power shell.

Comment: Currently, table transfer functionality in AzCopy hasn't been released as a library yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that there is an Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library that claims to power the Azcopy, but seems there is no direct way to copy tables according to the library reference.

As you mentioned that there is no method about copy tables in the [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library).

> prefer to integrate it in a C# project without using cmd.exe or power shell.

About how to operate Azure table storage with C#, we could refer to [Get started with Azure Table storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet).

> I have millions of entities to transfer now

As it is a huge number of entities need to be transfered. Based on my experience, we could use the [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) to do that.

**Related resources:**

[ETL using azure table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447778/etl-using-azure-table-storage?answertab=active#tab-top)

[Copy data to or from Azure Table using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage)